# CSV Export and download causes Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

I have a php script that queries a rather large database and stores results into a CSV. I keep getting a 500 Internal Server error when trying to download the file.

My hunch is that since there's over 2000+ rows that it needs to put into the CSV, that it is timing out. I have my code in a text file.

What can I do to fix this? Is this something that needs to be done in php.ini or do I need to SSH and modify the mysql timeout? Am I just going about this all wrong and I should be storing it to the server?

Just need a little direction on how this should be done. Thanks in advance.

http://andreawine.ladev.co/csv-export.txt

Comment: If possible check the server error log for exact cause of error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the specific cause of the 500 error in your PHP error log, but if it is in fact a script timeout, there are multiple ways to set a timeout limit.

You can increase the amount of time this (and only this) script is allowed to run by using the `set_time_limit(TIMEOUT)` function, assuming you aren't using `safe mode`, where `TIMEOUT` is the maximum number of seconds - http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

You can increase the amount of time all scripts on your server are allowed to run by setting the `max_execution_time TIMEOUT` to a higher value in `php.ini` where `TIMEOUT` is the maxiumn number of seconds - http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

You can increase the amount of time a script on a particular site, or below a particular folder, can run by setting the value in an `.htaccess` file using `php_value max_execution_time TIMEOUT` where `TIMEOUT` is the maximum number of seconds.